# AngularJS: Directive unable to use function for templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Thanks in advance for helping out a newbie to the world of angular.

Using angularjs 1.2.23 it seems that within a directive it should be able to [set the templateUrl using a function](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/guide/directive).

Currently the following code works fine using a simple string as the template URL:

```
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function (angular) {

var myModule = angular.module('myModule',[]);

myModule.directive("myDirective", function() {
return {
    restrict : "A",
    templateUrl: '/app/some/directory/template.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        elem.find('a.modal-trigger').bind('click', function(e) {
            elem.find('div.modal').modal('show');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        elem.find('a.modal-close').bind('click', function(e) {
            elem.find('div.modal').modal('hide');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    }
};
});

return myModule;

});
```

However when a function is put in place of the string (following the documentation and examples others have provided in other places on the web), then the function code itself is returned.

```
  templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
    return '/app/some/directory/template.html';
  }
```

For example, thus is what the request URL shows when the templte is called in:

```
http://myserver.com/function%20()%7Breturn%20'/app/some/directory/template.html'%7D
```

I've tried quite a few things, including playing with `compile`, but can't seem to get it to work.

Does this work in 1.2.23 ([people say it was since 1.1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1039))? I assume it does, and that I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: Seems to work fine over here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/CvtSTdfduLej9zrjSB3C?p=preview. You sure you don't have quotes around your function or anything?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thanks Phil, much appreciated!